# JPA select entity and use subquery to assign value in entity all within a single query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

I'm having some trouble with a JPA query. I should tell you now, I'm not an expert in JPA at all.

I have two classes, `Line` and `LineData`.

The relationship between `Line` and `LineData` is that a Line can potentially have 100s of `LineData` objects associated to it. The reason I haven't explicitly joined them is because most of the time when I retrieve a `Line` entity, I don't need the `LineData` (and seeing as there could be 100s, it would be a waste to load them all and then not use them).

However, what I would like to be able to do, when retrieving a `Line` entity, is get the maximum `LineData.value1` value as well and return that as a part of the `Line` entity, as `Line.maxVal1` . I've tried doing this with the following query:

```
SELECT l, l.maxVal1 = (SELECT MAX(d.value1) FROM LineData d WHERE d.name = l.name)
FROM Line l
WHERE l.name = example123
ORDER BY l.name ASC
```

But `Line.maxVal1` is coming back as `null`. I have tried the subquery on its own and it does return an actual value. Is it possibly to do what I'm trying here? If so, how?

Here are simplified versions of my classes:

```
public class Line {
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String name;

    @Column
    public boolean active;

    @Transient
    public Integer maxVal1;
}

public class LineData {
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public String name;
    @Column
    public Integer value1;
    @Column
    public Integer value2;
    @Column
    public Integer value3;
    ...
    @Column
    public Integer activeN;
}
```

*EDIT*
Here's an example of the what the database values would look like:

```
Line
name       | active
======================
example123 | true
example234 | false
example345 | true

LineData
name       | value1 | value2 | ... | valueN
============================================
example123 | 1      | 2      |     | 1
example123 | 3      | 2      |     | 1
example345 | 1      | 2      |     | 1
example123 | 14     | 2      |     | 1
example123 | 2      | 2      |     | 1
example123 | 2      | 2      |     | 1
example123 | 3      | 2      |     | 1
```

And the result of the query returning a Line object, with the values:

```
name       | active | maxVal1
==============================
example123 | true   | 14
```

Comment: Did you try `SELECT l, (SELECT MAX(d.value1)... ) AS l.maxVal1 .....`?

Comment: @Mubin I did try that, but I get an IllegalArgumentException because it doesn't like the `.` in `l.maxVal1`

Comment: I don't have an environment set up to test, can you see if you get the value if you use the query like: `SELECT l.name, (SELECT MAX(d.value1)... ) AS l.maxVal1 FROM Line l .....`

Comment: Select and assign a value in the query, I don't think that's the right way to do it. Do you have a one-to-many relationship setup? If yes may be you can try a join. Something like `select l from Line l join l.lineDatas d where d.id = (...)`.

Comment: @Mubin still getting the same error as before.

Comment: @BheshGurung I don't have a One-to-Many relationship set up, but that wouldn't help as I'm retrieving the "One", but doing the computation on the "Many", if that makes sense :P

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to retrieve the "one", with the "list of many" in the one with only the max of many. :))

Answer (score 1):

If you use hibernate you can try `@Formula`

```
public class Line {
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String name;

    @Column
    public boolean active;

    @Formula("(SELECT MAX(d.value1) FROM LineData d WHERE d.name = name)")
    public Integer maxVal1;
}
```

The `@Formula` contains native SQL - no HQL

Comment: I tried this, but I still got an error. Either way, I'd rather not use native SQL.

Comment: Please, can you post the error while I am thinking about another solution?